# Turn off computer when screen is powered down ( windows 7)

Tags: windows, service, screen, shutdown

Mostly out of curiosity, i was wondering how should i approach this. I'd like to make it so that when i turn off my screen, the computer shuts down. In essence, i'd like to make a service that constantly check whether the screen is on or off.

Any ideas/suggestions are welcome. Thank you for taking the time and i wish you all a plesant day.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if there would be a way to check the status of the connected monitors and you shut your computer down when the screen goes off, how do you plan to turn your computer on again? I expect then you have to use the normal hardware button on your tower. Why not stick to these buttons? It has worked the last 30 years or so...

To make an actual suggestion:

- Setup a webcam to monitor your screen. Using simple picture analysis you can detect if the screen is on or off
- Shutdown your computer down when screen goes off
- Also you can monitor the szenario when turning your screen on. You should see a manufacturers logo for a few seconds or somethinglike this. (Now you need a second computer with a second webcam)
- With the second computer you can build some little machine that pushes the power on button on your first computer to turn it on
- But how to turn on/off the second computer? Well, you need another one for that...